# modifying argument value within function

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to modify the order of a list of tuples within a function without returning the list.

For example:

```
L = [(2,4),(8,5),(1,3),(9,4)]
def sort_ratios(L):
    L = sorted(L, key=lambda x: float(x[0])/float(x[1]))
    return L
```

Thus, calling sort_ratios() outputs:

```
>>>sort_ratios(L)
[(1,3),(2,4),(8,5),(9,4)]
```

But `L` would still be `[(2,4),(8,5),(1,3),(9,4)]`
Instead, I would like to simply modify the value of L without returning anything so that `sort_ratios()` operates as follows:

```
>>>sort_ratios(L)
>>>L
[(1,3),(2,4),(8,5),(9,4)]
```

It seems trivial, but I just can't seem to get the function to operate this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `L.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0])/float(x[1]))` for an in-place sort.